# Get RIA WCF domain service returned 'OUTPUT' parameter

Tags: silverlight, wcf, mvvm

On my MVVM Silverlight application I need to call Domain service function to get both sql query result and some 'OUTPUT' data from stored procedure.  I figure out how to get the data on Domain Service side but on client I don't know how to get the 'OUTPUT' parameters from the function since Silverlight is async call.  The following is my function on Domain Service and I need get the two returned OUTPUT parameters from the async call.

Thanks for any help.

CK

```
  [Invoke]
    public IEnumerable<sp_Inquiry_Result> GetResultAsync( string ID, 
                                                          out string sDescription, 
                                                          out float fvariance)
    {

        // Declare ObjectParameter object to store output param
        ObjectParameter WorkcenterDescription = new ObjectParameter("@Description", typeof(string));         
        ObjectParameter Variance = new ObjectParameter("@Variance", typeof(float));

        // Call stored procedure, passing in Object Parameter
        ObjectResult < sp_WorkcenterCostInquiry_Result > o = this.ObjectContext.sp_Inquiry(
            workcenterID, 
            Variance);

        // ObjectParameter will have output param value from stored proc
        sDescription = Convert.ToString(Description.Value);
        fvariance = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Variance.Value);

        return o.ToList().AsEnumerable();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIA Services dos not support `out` parameters. They would not make any sense to an asynchronous call (any out results are being ignored behind the scenes of the service call).

The standard approach is create a result object containing multiple properties and return that  instead.

In your specific example that would been a new return type that includes these properties:

- sp_Inquiry_Result
- sDescription
- fvariance

Comment: Really appreciate your great answer.  Now I try to use 'VS2010' to 'Add function import' with the result of created column info complex collection data type but I did not see the 'OUTPUT' parameters on the stored proc column info list.  The returned inquiry result is a list and the OUTPUT params are single string and a float value.  Do you know how to add these two out params into the EDM model on vs2010 ria wcf web project?  Thanks again.

Comment: Don't try to add them to the EDM model unless they are actually part of your data. Create your own POCOs and your own RIA methods that return an IEnumerable of 1 entry.